# Searching multiple (varying) user inputs on a SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite

So I've been fiddling around with Recycler View and SQLite recently and I fear I am stumped.

The challenge is:
Theres a EditText view where an user can search up cars by simply naming them, be it by model, maker or even both:

"Hon" returns: HONda civic

"c" returns honda Civic, ford foCus, Chevrolet onix

The problem arises when I try to use more than one keyword:

"hon c" returns: HONda civic, HONda civic, ford foCus, Chevrolet onix (I will explain the double honda civic bug)

But first, here's the code:

```
for(String s : query.split(" ")) {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from brasil WHERE (maker LIKE '%" + s + "%' or model LIKE '%" + s + "%')" , null);

        if(cursor != null  && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                Car car = new Car(
                        cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3),
                        cursor.getInt(4),
                        cursor.getInt(5)
                );
                cars.add(car);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

The double Honda Civic bug happens because:
"Hon c" 2 strings so 2 loops
it finds hon in honda and c in civic, both cases gets added to the array of returning data.

Now what I wanted to happen :
"Hon c"
finds "hon" and "c" in honda civic so it gets added.

finds "c" but no "hon" on the others, so they shouldn't get added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of what Muthukrishnan said, I think you need to `select distinct` and an `AND` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
String query = "Select distinct * from brasil WHERE (";

String[] values = query.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(i != 0) {
        query += " AND ";
    }

    query += "(maker LIKE '%" + values[i] + "%' or model LIKE '%" + values[i] + "%')";
}
query += ")";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);

if(cursor != null  && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        Car car = new Car(
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getInt(4),
                cursor.getInt(5)
        );
        cars.add(car);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

This should give you only "Honda Civic" if you search "hon c".

Comment: I see, the guy above you also provided a solution by building a full String from a loop on every keyword, it worked, but it still shows unwanted results: 

for example: 

"honda c" returns honda civic and Chevrolet onix because the latter has "c" on it, but in that case I would want it to refine the resuts into only honda civic because chevrolet onix doens't have "honda" in it..

Another example:
"c" should return chevrolet onix and honda civic, but "c h" or "c ho" or "c hon" should only return honda civic

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the code you inserted until a minute ago. I just updated to reflect the edits in your question, so I think this should solve it now.

Comment: That worked wonders! Thank you so much! I didn't know the "distinct" possibility.. thank you!

Comment: Great! If this solved everything, could you select this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this to get duplicate out,

```
String query = "Select * from brasil WHERE (";

String[] values = query.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(i != 0) {
        query += " OR ";
    }

    query += "maker LIKE '%" + values[i] + "%' or model LIKE '%" + values[i] + "%' ";
}
query += ")";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);

if(cursor != null  && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        Car car = new Car(
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getInt(4),
                cursor.getInt(5)
        );
        cars.add(car);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the duplicate problem, although I still cant figure out a way to filter ONLY the results where "hon" AND "c" are found..

Comment: Your result should have this only right..? **HONda civic, ford foCus, Chevrolet onix**

Comment: or your result should have **HONda civic, Chevrolet onix** this 2 only.?

Comment: Let me ask better:

If a user types "honda", it should display honda civic, if the user presses "honda c" it should still only appear honda civic and no chevrolet because chevrolet doesn't have "honda" in it